# kget showing in application but not opening

Tags: appmenu

i ran the command int terminal
kget
it shows the following output
nitesh@nitesh:~$ kget
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
kget is already running!
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
how can i stop it
i also ran the command
sudo top
but it does not show running kget
please help me

Answer (score 2):

For me `ps -aux` (or similar) *does* show kget as running but the window won't display. It was working fine until a couple of days ago, nothing was changed it just stopped displaying the kget window when the application was called (from flashgot plugin in Firefox 37 on Kubuntu).

The fix was to edit `kgetrc`, e.g. `nano ~/.kde/share/config/kgetrc`, and alter the line `ShowMain=false` to read `ShowMain=true`. However, after rebooting I've found this has at some point been reverted.

My kget gives the following on startup from the command line:

```
k1410:~$ kget
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
KGlobal::locale(): Warning your global KLocale is being recreated with a valid main component instead of a fake component, this usually means you tried to call i18n related functions before your main component was created. You should not do that since it most likely will not work
QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
```

Usually then `killall kget` is necessary to kill the hidden application; then just `kget` from the commandline or selecting from the application menu works as expected.

If you have the same problem as me then you'll need to trace what's resetting the kgetrc (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672039/see-what-process-last-touched-a-file and look at `auditd` package and `auditctl` tool); a workaround might be to set kgetrc read only, eg `chmod a-w ~/.kde/share/config/kgetrc`.

Comment: Editting kgetrc at `ShowMain=true`  helped me. Then I went to "Integration" option and "uncheck" the box for "Use as download manager for Konqueror".